# Page slider with mustache template

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, mustache

I have started developing my first cordova SPA using mustache and javascript (with laravel backend).

---

My question is how should i go with sliding pages in and out on navigation, when there is only one div on screen always?

My html:

```html
<div id="content">

</div>
```

Template:

```html
<script type="text/mustache" id="aboutTemplate">
        <div>
                <header class="bar bar-nav">
                        <h1 class="title">About</h1>
                        <a class="btn btn-link btn-nav" href="#">
                            <span class="icon icon-left-nav"></span> &nbsp;&nbsp; Home
                        </a>
                </header>

                <div class='content'>
                    <p> {{ title }}</p>
                    <p> {{ author }} </p>
                    <p> {{ content1 }} <br />
                        {{ content2 }} <br />
                    Contact:<a href="mailto:{{ content3 }}"> {{ content3 }} </a>
                    </p>
                </div>
        </div>
        </script>
```

JS:

```js
(function () {

   
    router.addRoute('about', function() {
  about();
  
    });

 
    router.start();

    /*------Pages------*/
 function about() {

  var data = { title: 'xxxxx',
      author: 'Dima Daniel', 
      content1 :'xxxxxxxxxx.',
      content2 : 'Made by: Dima Daniel.',
      content3 : 'xxxxxx'
     }
      var template = $("#aboutTemplate").html();
   var html = Mustache.to_html(template, data);
   $('#content').html(html);
 }

 /*....Pages END....*/

}());
```